# Building a JavaScript grid with odd and even characters using two loops

Tags: javascript, grid

This is my first question on StackOverflow.

I have to build `gridGenerator(num)`. If `num` is `3`, it would look like this:

```
#_#
_#_
#_#
```

If `num` is `4`, it would look like this:

```
#_#_
_#_#
#_#_
_#_#
```

I was able to solve it for odd numbers, but struggle to adjust it to even numbers.

```js
function gridGenerator(num) {
  var grid = '';
  var row = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {

      if (row.length % 2) {
        row += '_';
      } else {
        row += '#';
      }
    }
    grid += row.slice(-num) + '\n';
  }
  return grid;
}

console.log(gridGenerator(3));
```

Need a hint how to solve it for `2`, `4`, and other even numbers. Thank you!

Comment: The first row starts off with `#`, and then alternates (so `#_#`), and then the next row starts with `_` (`_#_`). That might help.

Comment: Do you want it for a general case? I have a solution but don't want to spoil your fun.

Comment: This is one of the exercises for the boot camp preps.

Comment: Here's a hint. Describe the cases where you would place a "#" in terms of the oddness and even-ness of the row and column it goes into. Now ask if your code implements the analytical solution you came to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this 
**if ((i+j) % 2)**

```js
function gridGenerator(num) {
  var grid = '';
  var row = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
      if ((i+j) % 2) {
        row += '_';
      } else {
        row += '#';
      }
    }
    grid += row.slice(-num) + '\n';
  }
  return grid;
}

console.log(gridGenerator(4));
```

Comment: Genius in its simplicity! I was scratching my head trying to think of the combination to switch it at the end of each row ;)

Comment: :) Thanks. I just think a while and got this Idea ;) :)

Comment: Odd that this answer is higher rated than the answer that does the same thing yet takes less memory and operations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the condition `num % 2` to determine if a number is even or odd. I would use two loops like you are doing. Make your character addition based on the even / odd state of the row and column. At the end of each row insert the line break.

EDIT: Here you go.

```js
function generateGrid( num ) {
  let i, j, grid = "";
  
  for ( i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < num; j++ ) {
      if ( ( i + j ) % 2 ) {
        grid += "_";
      } else {
       grid += "#";
      }
    }        
    grid += "\n";
  }      
  return grid;
}

var grid = generateGrid( 4 );

console.log( grid );
```

Comment: I was trying to do it that way but had the same problem with even num.

Comment: I actually had a solution almost exactly like the one you accepted, but didn't want to give you code because I figured you wanted to figure it out yourself :)

Comment: Can you share yours please?

Comment: Sure but it's almost exactly the same lol. Little quicker actually.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function gridGen(num) {
    var even = '';
    for (var i = 0; i< num ; i++)
        even += (i%2) ? '_' : '#';

    odd = even.substring(1) + (num%2 ? '_' : '#');
    var out = '';
    for (var i = 0; i< num ; i++)
        out += ((i%2) ? odd : even) + '\n';
    return out;
}
console.log('Even Case');
console.log( gridGen(8));
console.log('Odd Case');
console.log( gridGen(7));
```

If you are looking for another approach + efficiency try this

Comment: Not Working try gridGen(2)

Comment: try with **gridGen(4)**

Comment: oops, I didn't convert it properly from ES6, should be good now

Comment: First you check don't do for odd numbers only try for even as well lets try with **console.log( gridGen(20));** ad check last **underscore**

Comment: @SourabhSomani If you read the code more carefully you will notice that `odd` is generated from `even` by repositioning the first and last element

Comment: Error in your even case. Check last column of even case.